# how to calculate data inputs from textbox in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a calorie calculator. As i am new to python i am not familiar with the working of it.There is no error but the output is zero i cannot seem to figure out why the calculation is  not working.Also i am showing the output in a textbox.Can somebody check why it is not working

```
class user:
        def __init__(self,window):
            self.window = window

            self.frame = Frame(self.window, bg = 'White', width=700,height=500)


            option = StringVar()
            dblcalorie = float()
            self.gain = gain = float()
            activity_level = float()
            self.age = Label (self.frame,text ='AGE :',fg ='black',font=('Georgia',14,'bold'))
            self.age_text = int
            self.agee = Entry(self.frame,textvariable = self.age_text, fg = 'black',width = 250)

            self.height = Label (self.frame, text='Height :', fg = 'black', font = ('Georgia', 14, 'bold'))
            self.height_text = int
            self.height1 = Entry (self.frame,textvariable = self.height_text, fg ='black', width = 250 )

            self.weight = Label (self.frame, text ='weight :', fg ='black', font =('Georgia', 14, 'bold'))
            self.weight_text = int
            self.weight1 = Entry (self.frame, textvariable = self.weight_text, fg ='black', width = 250)
            option.set("men")
            self.radio = Label (self.frame,text = 'Gender',width=25, font = ('Arial',14))
            self.male = Radiobutton (self.frame,text = 'Male',variable = option, value = "men")
            self.female = Radiobutton (self.frame,text = 'female',variable = option, value = "women")
            self.activity = Label(self.frame,text ="Activity:",fg ='black', font =('Georgia', 14, 'bold'))
            self.combo = ttk.Combobox(self.frame,values=["light","normal","heavy"])
            self.gainl=Label(self.frame,text='Gain:',fg ='black', font =('Georgia', 14, 'bold'))
            self.gain = Text(self.frame,width = 250, font = ('Arial',14))
            self.buttoncal = Button(self.frame,text='calculate',bg='gray',fg='gray12',font=('Georgia',14,'bold'),cursor='hand2',  command = lambda: self.calculate(activity_level))



        def gender(self):
               if self.option.get() =="men":
                    dblcalorie = (13.397 * int(self.weight_text.get())) + (4.799 * int(self.height_text.get())) - (5.677 * int(self.age_text.get())) + 88.362

               else:
                  dblcalorie = (13 * int(self.weight_text.get())) + (4 * int(self.height_text.get())) - ( 5 * int(self.age_text.get())) + 88


                return dblcalorie
        def activity(self,dblcalorie):

            if len(self.combo.get()) == 0:
                  messagebox.showinfo("ERROR", "please choose one activity level ")
            elif self.combo.get() == 'light':
                 activity_level = 1.375 * dblcalorie

            elif self.combo.get() == 'moderate':
                  activity_level = 1.55 * dblcalorie

            elif self.combo.get() == 'heavy':
                  activity_level = 1.725 * dblcalorie

            elif self.combo == 'extreme':
                  activity_level = 1.9 * dblcalorie

            return activity_level

        def calculate(self,activity_level):

               self.gain.insert(END,str(activity_level))
```

Comment: Read up on [Python Classes and Objects, Section "The self|Class and Instance Variables"](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-classes-and-objects/). Do `print(activity_level)` inside `def calculate(...` to see what you get.

Comment: First fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: `activity()` can error if the first condition is met. Due to the 1st condition not defining `activity_level` the return line will error. You `gender()` method can error as well as the `else` portion has a `+` at the end but nothing on the right side of the `+`.

Answer (score -1):

the last def is not tabbed out far enough try that.

Comment: Even though OP fix that indentation issue, but still not fix the `the output is zero` issue mentioned.  Also there is not only one indentation issue in the posted code.